# How to convert From string to image file

Tags: android, image

I am developing a simple android photo uploader. I have a Gallery activity, there I can select the pictures. After that I am sending the image names with path because i need to show them.

How can I make files out of these names and point to the actual image for the upload?

```
  String[] picturesWithPath = new String[arrPath.size()];
  for (int z = 0; z < arrPath.size(); z++)
    {
        picturesWithPath[z] = arrPath.get(z);

        Log.i("data","with path: "+picturesWithPath[z]);
    }
```

Comment: You cannot make files from names. It is very unclear what you want to upload. File names? Files? Please make your intention clear first.

Comment: i want to upload files. before that, i have to check the files MD5 checksum with the server. If I cant do this way, how I approach?

Comment: That looks like a very different problem. You first only talked about names and paths. There is no md5 code in your post. And moreover if you determine a md5 checksum for a file on your device then how would a server determine if it is ok before you upload the file? Please edit your post and write a good story about what you want. Dont use comments for that.

Answer (score 0):

- Use bellow code for get file URL.

  ```
    //use this in yorr for loop
    picturesWithPath[z] = getPath(Yourclass.this, arrPath.get(z));



   public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

  // check here to KITKAT or new version
  final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

  // DocumentProvider
  if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

      // ExternalStorageProvider
      if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
          final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
          final String[] split = docId.split(":");
          final String type = split[0];

          if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
              return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                      + split[1];
          }
      }
      // DownloadsProvider
      else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

          final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
          final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                  Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                  Long.valueOf(id));

          return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
      }
      // MediaProvider
      else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
          final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
          final String[] split = docId.split(":");
          final String type = split[0];

          Uri contentUri = null;
          if ("image".equals(type)) {
              contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
          } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
              contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
          } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
              contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
          }

          final String selection = "_id=?";
          final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

          return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                  selectionArgs);
      }
  }
  // MediaStore (and general)
  else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

      // Return the remote address
      if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
          return uri.getLastPathSegment();

      return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
  }
  // File
  else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
      return uri.getPath();
  }

  return null;
  }
   public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                 String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
  Cursor cursor = null;
  final String column = "_data";
  final String[] projection = { column };

  try {
      cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
              selection, selectionArgs, null);
      if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
          return cursor.getString(index);
      }
  } finally {
      if (cursor != null)
          cursor.close();
  }
  return null;
  }
  public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
  return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri
          .getAuthority());
  }
  public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
  return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri
          .getAuthority());
  }
  public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
  return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri
          .getAuthority());

  public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
  return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri
          .getAuthority());
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but i already  have the files path with name like storage/emulated/0/Download/download.jpg. Now i need to make file out of them. How to do that?

Comment: It means you show image on imageview using this path right

Comment: i dont need to show the image, i just want to make a FILE object, to be able to upload to the server.